# Why does Resharper intellisense replace my code?

Tags: c#, resharper

With Resharper 6.1, when I type something like...
  widget.PropertyA

and then put my cursor in front of the widget symbol like this...

|widget.PropertyA

and start typing another symbol, R# intellisense pops up. If I choose a suggested symbol, then R# replaces the widget symbol with my newly chosen symbol.

I can see how this might be useful at times, but the vast majority of the time, I just want to type more code in front of widget and don't want it to be replaced. Does anyone know if this behavior is configurable?

Thanks.

Comment: I don't see the same side-effects.  R# never replaces the identifier...  Is this with VS 2010?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't believe it is configurable. It seems to be by design that Tab overwrites code. It will even highlight the segment of code that would be replaced.

Instead of hitting Tab to select your symbol, use Enter instead. It will insert the new code without overwriting the existing code.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't realize there was a difference between the behavior of the enter and the tab. It's a bit strange and I still wish it was configurable, but this will due. With about a million features that save my life, I can handle the occasional odd one.

Comment: Both do the same thing now. If you had the statement `new LiteDbRepository(poolDef.Value.BaseIdentifier, _dbFilesFolder, _log));` and you wanted to replace `LiteDbRepository` with `VelocityDbRepository`, and started typing, it doesnt matter if you Tab, Enter, or Ctrl+Space, everything after the newly inserted `VelocityDbRepository()` gets erased.

Comment: See Levi's answer, I confirmed it was configurable in ReSharper Ultimate 2017.3.5

Answer (score 8):

Go to `IntelliSense -> Completing Characters` in your ReSharper options. At the top of that menu you can whether the Enter and Tab keys insert or replace.

Comment: Wow. exactly what i was needed

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you can really do is to insert an extra space before you start typing. You could request that it be changed on [JetBrains' bug tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.net). Let me know if you do and I'll vote for it!

Comment: Such request would be a great candidate for a won't fix resolution: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/RSRP-20599 The Tab/Enter problem is FAQ but I guess it just takes a bit of effort to get used to

Comment: Huh, never realised there was a difference. Thanks :)